# Ударение "в петлю"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: "в петлЮ" или "в пЕтлю"? Я слышал оба варианта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пЕтля, пЕтли, пЕтле, пЕтлю, пЕтлей, (о) пЕтле - исторический вариант.
Сейчас большинством словарей допустимым считается ударение на последнем слоге (вместо или наряду со старым - тут словари расходятся).
При этом в некоторых устойчивых сочетаниях ("головой в пЕтлю", "слазил в пЕтлю" и проч.) старый вариант сохранился полностью.
*На цифре 26 один шагнул под пистолет,   

Другой же - в петлю слазил в "Англетере".*
(ВСВ)

В остальных случаях вы можете использовать и "в пЕтлю", и "в петлЮ", но тогда вам надо делать это последовательно, во всех падежах.